# Xcode: Make label click-through

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uilabel

I created a storyboard that contains some big buttons. For a specific reason I have to put another smaller button and a label over each big button. I would like to make it so that the smaller button and the label do not receive the click event, but the big button does.

I was looking for a way to make the label and the small button click-through, but I did not find any. And as a second requirement, I would *very* much like to make it so that both the big button's background image becomes dark + the small button's background image becomes dark and the label should not react at all.

Comment: on click of label or small button you dont want any action to be performed? or Big button's action method to be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set 1) Big button 2) Label & 3) Small button in xib. Then put button action in both.It should be working.

```
- (IBAction)bigButton:(id)sender {
// do nothing
}

- (IBAction)smallButton:(id)sender {
[self.bigButton setHighlighted:YES];
}
```

Comment: If you click the small button, it will intercept the event and the big button won’t receive it.

Comment: @zoul wrong. Please check attached sample example.https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90940570/Testing.zip

Comment: Your sample project does exactly what I said: when I tap the small button, it highlights and then triggers its own action. Whereas the poster wants both buttons to highlight and trigger the big button’s action.

Comment: @zoul then set background image of both buttons according to  requirements.

Comment: zoul, you have summarized it perfectly!

Comment: San, I do not have different background images for each state. I am using the built-in highlight function.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)"your small button action":(id)sender{
     [self "your big button action":nil];
}


-(IBAction)"your big button action":(id)sender{
    //setbackgroundimage for your small button here
}
```

Label would not react to click event anyway.So this may work.Try it

Comment: In general, that is really great, but how would I get my small button's background image to become dark when I press the big button?

Comment: Thank you, but I am not using a different background image, I am just using the built-in darkness that occurs when you click an image. I hope you know what I mean?